# how to implement BOXContentCacheClientProtocol in BOX Content SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, box

I am working with the [BOX Content SDK for iOS](https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk).  BOX generally recommends doing some sort of caching of API results in order to reduce the risk of hitting API throttling limits.  I see in the SDK there is a protocol named BOXContentCacheClientProtocol, and many API requests have methods that appear to use cached results.  For example, one of the requests for getting a folder's information:

```
- (void)performRequestWithCached:(BOXFolderBlock)cacheBlock
                       refreshed:(BOXFolderBlock)refreshBlock
{
  if (cacheBlock) {
    if ([self.cacheClient respondsToSelector:@selector(retrieveCacheForFolderRequest:completion:)]) {
      [self.cacheClient retrieveCacheForFolderRequest:self completion:cacheBlock];
    } else {
      cacheBlock(nil, nil);
    }
  }
  [self performRequestWithCompletion:refreshBlock];
}
```

It would seem to me that the correct way to implement retrieveCacheForFolderRequest in a cache client would be to store the results of each folder's request in cache and look them up by some sort of unique id.  If a request for a folder was previously made and has results in cache, simply return cached results.  Something like this:

```
- (void)retrieveCacheForFolderRequest:(BOXFolderRequest *)request 
                           completion:(BOXFolderBlock)completionBlock
{
  BOXFolder *cachedResult = [_cache objectForKey:request.folderID];
  if (cachedResult) {
    completionBlock(cachedResult, nil);
  }
}
```

However, looking at the source for performRequestWithCached, successfully finding a cached result would not prevent the request implementation from still calling the API to get the same results from the server.

Am I missing something?  Is the caller of performRequestWithCached supposed to cancel the request if the cacheBlock is called?  Hopefully someone from BOX will pick this up and provide some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right on cache client protocol implementation. For performRequestWithCached, the idea is that you populate UI from the cache block and refresh the cache and the UI after the refresh block eventually returns the latest data from the Box API. However if your use case is to first check cache before making a network call consider implementing cacheFolderRequest on the cacheclient protocol (https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk/blob/master/BoxContentSDK/BoxContentSDK/Protocols/BOXContentCacheClientProtocol.h#L172)

Alternatively you can still do a performRequestWithCached with refresh block set to nil (which skips the network call like so https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk/blob/master/BoxContentSDK/BoxContentSDK/Requests/BOXFolderRequest.m#L132) and then decide to make another call with the refresh block set this time to pull data from the network.